# filter all rows smaller than x with all following values also smaller than x

Tags: r, dplyr, window-functions

I am looking for a concise way to filter a data.frame for all rows smaller than a value x with all following values also smaller than x. I found a way but it is somehwat verbose. I tried to do it with `dplyr::cumall` and `cumany`, but was not able to figure it out.

Here is a small reprex including my actual approach. Ideally I would only have one `filter` line or `mutate` + `filter`, but with the current approach it takes two rounds of `mutate/filter`.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Original data
tbl <- tibble(value = c(100,100,100,10,10,5,10,10,5,5,5,1,1,1,1))

# desired output:
# keep only rows, where value is smaller than 5 and ...
# no value after that is larger than 5

tbl %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(value <= 5) %>%
  mutate(id2 = lead(id, default = max(id) + 1) - id) %>% 
  filter(id2 == 1)

#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   value    id   id2
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     5     9     1
#> 2     5    10     1
#> 3     5    11     1
#> 4     1    12     1
#> 5     1    13     1
#> 6     1    14     1
#> 7     1    15     1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine `cummin` with a reversed reverse `cummax`:

```r
 tbl %>% filter(rev(cummax(rev(value))) <= 5 & cummin(value) <= 5)
# A tibble: 7 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     5
2     5
3     5
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Somehow didn't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option is to use `subset` + `rle`

```
tblout <- subset(tbl,
                 with(rle(value<=5 & c(0,diff(value))<=0),
                      rep(lengths>1 & values,lengths)))
```

such that

```
> tblout
# A tibble: 7 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     5
2     5
3     5
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this base R alternative and the use of `with(rle(...))`